Ошибка при работе с aiogram в Python
Вот такая ошибка: ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' перепробовал все что только можно обновлял, удалял, переустанавливал aiogram, но executor не появляется

Плохо переустанавливали. executor убран из aiogram 3 - он устанавливается по умолчанию. А у вас же код написан для версии aiogram 2. Можно установить командой pip install aiogram==2.25.1

C версии 3 aiogram не перестал использовать executor для запуска бота ,и сейчас запуск выполняется с помощью библиотеки asyncio, это может выглядить так:
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage


async def main() -> None:
    bot: Bot = Bot(token='')
    dp: Dispatcher = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())

    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

